# Attachment extension is always html

Tags: django, attachment, file-extension

I have a Django view which outputs pdf like this:

```
def evaluation_download(request):
    ....

    response = HttpResponse()
    response["mimetype"] = "application/force-download"
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="evaluation.pdf"'
    c = canvas.Canvas(response)

    ....  # Draw stuff on canvas

    c.showPage()
    c.save()

    return response
```

This code correctly generates PDF file, but downloaded file's name is `evaluation.pdf.html`. Why?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to set an appropriate `content_type`:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="evaluation.pdf"'
```

Read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/outputting-pdf/#outputting-pdfs-with-django) for more information.